# Monitor pattern using boost threads

Tags: multithreading, boost, monitor, condition-variable

Being new to boost::thread I was trying the other day to write a BlockingQueue (in my opinion the most practical synchronization construct ever). That's accomplished either using a semaphore or a condition variable, did both previously on windows respectively linux but never using boost.

So, in languages where you have a "Monitor" available (you know, the one with lock, wait, and notify) you just use that:

```
T BlockingQueue::take()
{
    scopelock(monitor);
    while (queue.empty())
        monitor.wait();

    T ret = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    return ret;
}
```

From what I could tell the "Monitor" is accomplished using a boost::condition_variable_any in tandem with a boost::mutex. BUT, the condition_variable_any already contains a mutex! (called internal_mutex). So that's why I thought at first that condition_variable_any is the whole Monitor, but as it turns out the mutex is not accesible from outside and you can't lock it before waiting etc.

Anyone know what's the purpose of boost::condition_variable_any::internal_mutex? In my case, It got me really confused bc I know that waiting on a pthread_cond_t must be done with the mutex locked - but which mutex?? Thanks.

Comment: Read the docs, it's all there. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref